# Handling different versions of project and pushing changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have started to use Git (bitbucket) recently. I have a project and a corresponding workspace and a repository in bit bucket. Now I have the need to customize this project for different clients. How do I set this up? Create a new repository for every new client project under same workspace? Or create new workspace for each client project?

When a new common feature is to be added/ existing common feature is to be updated (for ex. only few files have code changes but to be applied to all client projects) how to handle this? Checking out each client project, making changes and pushing is lot of redundant work.

I went through lot of links but could not find a concrete answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of bitbucket workspaces look different depending on which organization you work for. For example our company uses workspaces for similar projects: `www.bitbucket.org/ecommerce-apps/amazon-integration` or `www.bitbucket.org/ai-components/machine-learning-template`

Although it makes logical sense to divide workspaces into different clients in order to keep the code base separate.

---

As to the common feature git structure, here is what I have done before.

Have a common-features.git repository to hold all the common files which stay the same between projects. This helps to keep track of versions of changes made to common files. If you were to make pull each repo, make changes manually, and push changes, there is no traceability and it is easy to make mistakes. Having a common repo allows one to keep track of who changed what and when.

When it comes time to update the project repo with the new files, one would clone the project repository, setup a second remote and pull changes from there.

```
git clone https://github.com/client1/project1
git remotes add upstream https://github.com/commons/common-features
git pull upstream branchname --allow-unrelated-histories
```

[image]

---

Unfortunately you would still have to do this for each project repository as there may be different things going on, such as different branches. Perhaps you want to update most projects with the latest features but only update other projects after some time.

If you insist on automating the updating of common feature changes, you could consider using [webhooks](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/manage-webhooks/) in order to push changes to other repos in the event of a push to master of the common repo.

Comment: I'm new to git so please bear with me. After the run the commands that you mentioned, my local repository Project1 has files from remote repo Project1 and remote common files. You mean now I need to push this version to remote Project1 so that it has latest files from remote common files?

Comment: @Nikki That is correct. You would then push the changes (the common files in local Project1) to the remote Project1.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But we might still have some conflicts here is it? Anyone checking out Project1 remote to their local repo is free to update common files there and push back to Project1 remote. At the same time anyone is free to checkout common features remote and do changes in local and push it back to common features remote. Then the common files both the remote repos are different now and we can't trace them really. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That is completely right, yes. To cater for that, we have written processes within the organization. For example, we restrict access to the common-features repo so that a few members of the group can make changes.

Comment: Another example of a process is this: one can only pull from common-repo releases/tags or master branch. So we know that there was a release 1.0.3 of common-releases and now we want project1 to also have the files of 1.0.3. The idea is for no one to change the common files in project1 so that the common-features repo remains the source of truth.